# ionic1 angular js ng-repeat | filter : search not working?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

```js
angular.module('starter.services', [])

 .factory('Chats', function($http) {
  // Might use a resource here that returns a JSON array

  // Some fake testing data
  var chats=[];
 $http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'js/champions.json'
}).then(function success(data) {
  for (var i = 1; i < 700; i++) {
    if (data.data.data[i]!=undefined) {
       chats.push(data.data.data[i]) ;
    //console.log(data.data.data[i]);
    }
  }
 });
//console.log(chats);
  return {
    all: function() {
      return chats;
    },

    remove: function(chat) {
      chats.splice(chats.indexOf(chat), 1);
    },
 
    get: function(chatId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < chats.length; i++) {
        if (chats[i].id === parseInt(chatId)) {
          return chats[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
}) ;
```

```html
<ion-view view-title=" Tüm Kahramanlar">
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label fixed>Arama</ion-label>
    <input type="text" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Karakter Adına Göre Filtrele" ng-model="search" ></input>
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="item-remove-animate item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="chat in chats  | orderBy : 'key' | filter :  search  "  type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/chats/{{chat.id}}">
        <img ng-src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/7.18.1/img/champion/{{chat.image.full}}">
        <h2>{{chat.name  }}</h2>
        <p>{{chat.title}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>

        <ion-option-button class="button-assertive" ng-click="remove(chat)">
          Delete
        </ion-option-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Guys , How can ı filter this ng repeat code its coming like nothing happened. so its not filtered . please help me :( ı think its  model think not changed  when ı am write | filter : 'NameSomething' its Working but ı cant get in there ng model how can ı do this :?

[image: its my output.]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

Change this line : (Make sure you define `$scope.search = {};` in controller)

```
<input type="text" style="width: 100%" placeholder="Karakter Adına Göre Filtrele" ng-model="search.name" ></input>
```

**Simple Implementation :**
Search with name:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchData.name">
<div ng-repeat="chat in chats | filter:searchData"> {{chat.name}}</div>
```

**Working Demo :**

https://plnkr.co/edit/t6B6fZDRCSLuBN36GLVD?p=preview

Comment: sorry man its not working ng repeat working but not filtering.

Comment: thanks. I tried and tried. Thank you very much . What was wrong with me. Should I send an array to the filter?

Comment: Yes, You need to send object to it